# Get build steps using Jenkins Pipeline REST API

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-blueocean

I would like to ask is there any way to query run time build steps by using Jenkins pipeline REST API? I refer to this link https://github.com/jenkinsci/pipeline-stage-view-plugin/tree/master/rest-api and it seems like I can't get a run time build steps command line that I configure for Jenkins pipeline job.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Using pipeline-stage-view-plugin API `/job/myJob/2/execution/node/54/wfapi/describe` I see JSON results like `"name": "Shell Script", "parameterDescription": "git clean -xfd",` which corresponds to my Jenkinsfile: `sh "git clean -xfd"`. Can you expand what information you can't get?

Answer (score 0):

It seems there is no possibility to get this information via the REST API. I found a solution somewhere.
With

http://*Serverurl*/job/*jobname*/config.xml

you can download the config file and parse the XML. Doing it with PowerShell and it's working fine.